# Context for isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)

Tags: android

What is the right context to pass to the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)` method?

Comment: There only one type of context ;)

Comment: You can pass an `Activity` Context or an `Application` context.

Comment: I don't really agree with you, in my case i tried with the Application Context and the Activity Context , they both didn't work. @Slyzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass anyone context like:

1. Activity context (By passing `this`) ,
2. Application context (by getting through `getApplicationContext()`),
3. Base context (By getting through `getBaseContext()`) etc.

actually `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` attached to **whole application** not an single activity that's why you can use anyone context object.

Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I just use the Activity context where users land when they start up my app, and that's worked (we've had it show up in testing here).

My code in that Activity is this:

```
private void checkPlayServices() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        } else {
            ToastHelper.showCenteredToast("Until you update your Google Play Services, this app cannot run on this phone");
            finish();
        }
    }
```

You can see on the first line of the function that I'm passing `this` into the check, and that just maps to an `Activity`.